# Bootstrap Grid Responsive

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function() {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            next = next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });


});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,900,700);

html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.125rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #444;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 55px 0 35px;
}

a {
    color: #ddd;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 20px;
    &:hover {
        color: #ccc;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}

.carousel-inner {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.carousel-control {
    width: 4%;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    color: #444;
}

.carousel-inner {
    a {
        display: table-cell;
        height: 180px;
        width: 200px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    img {
        max-height: 150px;
        margin: auto auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-inner>.item.next,
    .carousel-inner>.item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-inner>.item.prev,
    .carousel-inner>.item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .carousel-inner>.item.next,
    .carousel-inner>.item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-inner>.item.prev,
    .carousel-inner>.item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

    .carousel-inner>.item.next,
    .carousel-inner>.item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-inner>.item.prev,
    .carousel-inner>.item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <h3>Multiple Item Product Carousel Bootstrap 3.3.6<br><a href="#">Thanks to and Refrence @Maurice and Icons8</a></h3></div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/pineapple-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/paprika-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/avocado-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Food/banana-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/onion-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Food/asparagus-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Plants/watermelon-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/96/Food/eggplant-96.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When in desktop mode, it displays 6 images
I want to show in mobile mode only and How to make 768px screen mode, only display 4 images per row, instead of 6 images?
show 4 cards  at 768px
It applies to the lower screen mode
I use bootstrap, javascrip, html

When in desktop mode, it displays 6 images
I want to show in mobile mode only and How to make 768px screen mode, only display 4 images per row, instead of 6 images?
show 4 cards  at 768px
It applies to the lower screen mode
I use bootstrap, javascrip, html

Comment: @jafarbtech Please read the description of the bootstrapping tag before applying to any questions.. It has nothing to do with Bootstrap

Comment: @j08691 oh sorry I mistakenly added it in place of `twitter-bootstrap` tag